# Is my data hidden from search engines?

Tags: seo

I've created a website that connects stores with brands. Many stores can have the same brand.

You can search for a brand and see what stores sells this brand (picture).
`www.mysite.com/?id=23&brand=my+brand+name`

If you open a store, you can see what brands they have.
`www.mysite.com/?id=235&store=my+store+name`

When you open a brand, the entire store list is loaded but hidden. Through jQuery and drop down list I can change city and the map and store list will be updated dynamically.

But if I want to score higher on search engines, e.g. when users google for  `"dovre oslo"`
, I would like the search engine to find all the stores

Since I'm trying to rank higher on search engines, would it be better if the entire page reloaded and adding city name in the URL?

And when opening a store page, should I add the city name in the URL?

[image]

Comment: You can add a city .. it won't hurt; just if an end-user types in that particular city or region, it might bump you up in the SERPS.  But I think the entire issue you raised is small; I'd concentrate more on quality, relevant backlinks (links pointing to your domain), and getting listed in quality, relevant directories, such as dmoz.org, but not link farms.  And if you want to prepare your website for the future, look into schema.org and create rich snippets. It's a ton of work, but well worth it, imo.  And of course, all the social media ... have a FB, TWitter, etc., page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussions and thoughts, I've come to the conclusion that it doesn't matter if I use drop downs and jQuery.

All my pages are listed in my site maps and therefore visible to search engines.